# Unity3d: Get a direction vector parallel to plane

Tags: unity, mathematics, vector, raycasting, projection

[image]

I need to send a raycast from my camera which is parallel to the plane (Ground) and in the same direction of its forward vector (Represented by the black color vector)

I cant use world space direction because the global forward vector of the camera points at the same direction no matter how much I rotate it (Since its a VR camera)

I tried to use [Vector3.ProjectOnPlane](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.ProjectOnPlane.html), but not sure how it works.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you want to get a forward vector parallel to the ground plane relative to the camera's rotation, from what I can get.

The solution is as simple as using **[Vector3.Cross(Vector a, Vector b)](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Cross.html)**, it is not commutative, so you'll have to give the vectors in the correct order. What the cross product gives you, is a vector C perpendicular to 2 vectors A and B. So, both vectors you'll have to pass as parameters in the function are the camera's **transform.right** and the plane's normal (as an Y vector) as A and B respectively, so you get a forward vector parallel to the ground's plane.

One of the ways to get a ground's normal is by using **[Physics' API](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.html)** functions such as Raycast, Spherecast, Boxcast, etc., where you can obtain the RaycastHit information of the ground you are contacting.

For the sake of a simple example, you could try this with **[Raycast](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html)**:

```
public class GetForwardVector : MonoBehaviour
{
    public LayerMask mask;
    public float distance;
    public Vector3 forward;

    public void Update()
    {
        RaycastHit hit;

        if(Physics.Raycast(transform.position, -transform.up, out hit, distance, mask))
        {
            forward = Vector3.Cross(transform.right, hit.normal);
        }
    }
}
```

Here, if the script was attached to the camera, a ray is casted from the camera's position, taking the camera's relative down direction, to obtain the information of the ground below it.

Hope it helps.